# Background Position Array when generate pdf using dompdf

Tags: php, dompdf

I try to generate pdf file using library dompdf in php but found the following error.

A PHP Error was encountered

> ```
> Severity: Warning
> Message: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given
> Filename: include/style.cls.php
> Line Number: 1061
> ```

I tried to debug and found this array that cause error

```
array
  'background_position' => 
    array
      0 => string '0%' (length=2)
      'x' => string '0%' (length=2)
      1 => string '0%' (length=2)
      'y' => string '0%' (length=2)
  'background' => string 'none' (length=4)
```

My question is how can i fixed this error, where this array come from?

Appreciate for any response.

thanks,
Frans

Comment: It wasn't a PHP error, it is a warning.

Comment: And by "it is a warning" @DreamEater means that if you suppress warnings your PDF will render just fine. Warnings do not halt PDF rendering, but if displayed to the web browser they will prevent dompdf from streaming the PDF.

Answer (score 0):

you must set `background_position` as string with space separator. Look for class code here [line 989 - begin of method](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/blob/master/include/style.cls.php#L989)

Comment: hi, thanks for your response.My question is, in which css actually cause the error, because I still can not relate this error and the cause css

Comment: @Frans we would need to see the document styling to know where the problem lies. But if you are using an older version of dompdf you might try upgrading. I seem to recall this being addressed.